# Using Composer locally then uploading files through FTP

Tags: php, composer-php

Bit of a strange set up but have come across a project where Composer has been used in a local environment to get a project started. The original developer did not have ssh access to the production server therefore he used Composer locally and uploaded the 'vendor' directory from his desktop to the server using FTP.

I now need to add the [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) package so have done the following locally on my Mac:

```
cd Desktop/
composer require phpmailer/phpmailer
```

This has created the following structure on my desktop:

```
Desktop/composer.json
Desktop/composer.lock
Desktop/vendor/autoload.php
Desktop/vendor/composer/*
Desktop/vendor/phpmailer/*
```

Which of these do I need to upload through FTP? I realise `vendor/phpmailer/*` is the package I want, so will need uploading.

What about the others? I already have an autoloader configured so guessing `vendor/autoload.php` is not required here?

`composer.json` I could add the package to what's already there, e.g.

```
"require": {
    *other packages here*
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^5.2"
}
```

But I wasn't sure if that's necessary because I'm not going to be using ssh/Composer on the server to run any updates?

Comment: It depends on what the phpmailer needs. Try creating an empty project and require-ing only phpmailer in composer. Just to see which packages it needs to run normally and upload only them via the FTP  client.

Comment: You don't upload anything in `vendor`. You upload `composer.lock` to the server, then run `composer install` on the server.

Comment: @ceejayoz re-read the post - we do not have access to the server to run any composer commands!

Comment: Just add the dependency to the project's composer.json file locally and `composer update`. After that just upload the vendor files.

Comment: You may want to run `composer depends phpmailer/phpmailer` to find out the other packages needed

Comment: @Katie thanks - the output is just `requires  phpmailer/phpmailer (^5.2)` so guessing this means it doesn't depend on any other packages?

Comment: @Andy, it can depend on many things, that is what Composer figures out for you and installs automatically

Comment: @ceejayoz Actually running Composer on the production server will some day destroy your working web site because something you need is down unexpectedly (like Github or any other service hosting the dependency version you need). And you'd be effectively stuck in this situation because a rollback also cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: @Sven Not if you've got a sensible blue-green deployment model.

Comment: @ceejayoz We are talking about FTP deployments here... F-T-P! I cannot imagine a worse protocol to get stuff onto the server. Anything sophisticated like you suggest very likely is out of range, isn't it?

Comment: @Sven and ceejayoz Just to clarify, this is not a normal or ordinary situation. The question was raised because it's a "one off" type of scenario where we are not able to use Composer on the server. If we could the question wouldn't even have been asked. Anything we're doing with Composer has to be done in our local environment and then whatever happens there has to go back to the server - in this case FTP is the only option to do that. I realise this is very backward but changing the way we access the server is not an option on this particular project which is why the question was raised.

Comment: As someone with the same problem I would like to give a hint:
I used Deployment with phpstorm to upload and compare the /vendor directory and it was pain in the ass, cause too slow.
What is far more efficient is too upload the whole /vendor directory with Filezilla

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual workflow would be:

1. Checkout the current version from the version control.
2. Add dependencies via command line `composer require new/package`.
3. This will download the new package and update the autoloading.
4. Test the result locally or on a test website environment.
5. If happy with the result, upload the whole folder to the production server.

There may be several exceptions from this general workflow:

ad 1: If there is no version control, you'd probably better of starting a local git repo right now, and download the current production state into it as the first commit. Not having version control will make things harder, especially going back to known working versions. And because the files on the production server are probably unmanaged, you'd also check in the `vendor` folder into your newly created version control just to avoid canceling any changes that had been made to these files.

ad 2: Manually editing the `composer.json` file sometimes is a faster way to get what you want if you know what you are doing, but you'd have to correctly edit the JSON. For me it usually is too much hassle if I already have a command line ready. The command will also select a matching version that fits into the already installed dependencies. Manual editing may lead to version conflicts that you'd have to untangle. Remember to only install dependencies that work with the PHP version in production. You probably should run `composer config platform.php X.Y.Z` in order to add the production version of PHP into the `composer.json` file, which prevents Composer from installing dependency versions based on your development PHP. Adding the `-g` switch will add this setting to your global (user) setting instead, which will affect all composer operations you start, also for other projects.

ad 3: Manual editing will require you to run `composer update` on the command line, so there's probably no reason to not do `composer require` instead.

ad 4: How this could be done is entirely dependent on what environment you have to work with.

ad 5: At this stage you have assembled all files necessary to create a working website. Uploading them to production will always result in a working website unless the upload fails somehow. You could also use some "upload first to temporary folder, then move on the server" approach if you fear FTP would be unreliable. Some people take a different approach: They have a git repository on the production server and they simply push the version that should go live onto that remote repo. Some post-push scripts will run `composer install` then. This automated approach will also work (but not using FTP), but has the higher risk of something failing during deployment, and probably has no easy way back to the previous situation.

So in the end I'd say that uploading the whole folder structure via FTP (well, that protocol is insecure itself, better replace it with FTPS (FTP with SSL), SFTP or SCP) is better compared to running Composer on the production server.

Your specific question regarding which folders to upload: All of them. Especially upload the whole `vendor` folder. It contains the current autoloader and all dependency packages the software needs. If you worked correctly, you downloaded the existing `composer.json` and `composer.lock` file together with everything else and added the new dependency to it. This has changed both these files, added the new package to the `vendor` folder and the classes to the autoloader.

Don't fiddle with uploading only parts of the `vendor` folder, or manually editing a component of the autoloading. You will only create surprises for the developer coming after you if you do some aspect incorrectly, and it also takes more time. Composer is a very good tool to manage dependencies - use it!

Comment: -1 for suggesting to checkin vendors in your git. It is simply not neccessary. Use tools like satis or make a tarball manually to save the versions. Including vendors into your git makes the whole composer concept obsolete.

Comment: @JochenSchultz: I read my answer again, and I fail to see where I _suggest_ to checkin `vendors`. Maybe you can point that out for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could copy the composer.json from the server to your local server, add the requirements and run composer update.

After that you can copy all files (composer.json, composer.lock and vendor folder to your server)...

---

Or you can copy local vendor/phpmailer into servers vendor folder, search for the entry of phpmailer in vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php and add it to your servers vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php.

Using this method also add phpmailers dependencies the same way.

```
composer depends phpmailer/phpmailer
```

Comment: -1 for suggesting to fiddle with folders and the autoloading, It's simply not worth it, but will likely introduce errors and nasty surprises.

Comment: The whole uploading vendors via ftp thing is nasty... 
When i had the same problem in one of our customers projects, i've let them set up a satis server and made a php script to generate the satis.json from the composer.json automatically. Of course it is not recomended to fiddle the files in the vendor folder. But when it comes to "customer: i need this script running in 15 seconds" it may help.

Comment: If you'd read the comment of the OP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41224832/using-composer-locally-then-uploading-files-through-ftp/41229978?noredirect=1#comment69677811_41224832 you'd understand that this question is specifically tailored to the situation that has to be dealt with - not the generic case.