# PHPWord Installation without composer

Tags: php, phpword

Forgive the seeming lameness here. I'm working with a shared hosting with onnly access to cpanel and host are not willing to install composer nor PHPWord on my behalf. Is it possible to install PHPWord by just downloading the ZIP from github? Thanks

Comment: Is the shared hosting limitation because of a client/work? Restricting yourself at the whim of a 3rd doesn't sound fun.

Comment: @castis host just said they don't support it and client already made a 12 month subscription. At the outset though, I didn't think I would need an extra component to convert word to pdf

Comment: I'm a bit flabbergasted with lots of people saying "just use composer" - if we do not want or cannot use it - for any reason - this should not be considered as a valid response - at all.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, I do it all the time.  For **PHPWord**, I would download the zip file from GitHub and move the contents of the *src* folder to a directory called "lib\PhpOffice\PhpWord".  You'll then need a PHP class loader.  I always use this for autoloading, provided the Classes are properly namespaced, which appears to be the case.

```
$GLOBALS['class_path'] = array(__DIR__ . '/lib', __DIR__);

// Set-up class_path superglobal variable using php include_path as basis
if (!array_key_exists('class_path', $GLOBALS)) {
    $GLOBALS['class_path'] = array();
    foreach (explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path()) as $path) {
        // substitute __DIR__ path for '.' instead
        if ($path == '.') {
            array_push( $GLOBALS['class_path'], realpath(__DIR__) );
            continue;
        }
        array_push( $GLOBALS['class_path'], realpath($path) );
    }
}

if (!function_exists('import')):
function import($package = '') {
    if (empty($package)) {
        trigger_error("Package path must be specified.", E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    $package_bits = explode('\\', $package);
    $package_path = implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $package_bits) . '.php';
    foreach ($GLOBALS['class_path'] as $path) {
        $file = $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $package_path;
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            require_once($file);
            $entity_name = implode('\\', $package_bits);
            if (!(class_exists($entity_name, false) ||
                interface_exists($entity_name, false)
                || trait_exists($entity_name, false))) {
            $caller = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS, 1)[0];
            trigger_error("Entity '" . $package . "' not found in file '" . $package_path . "' for import called in " .
                    $caller['file'] . " on line " . $caller['line'], E_USER_ERROR);
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
endif;

spl_autoload_register('import');
```

Set your $GLOBALS['class_path'] to the location of the '*lib*' directory and be sure to use '*use*' as needed before attempting to instantiate **PHPWord**.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for going a mile. Two things: going this route 1) any idea how to get the zend components: Zend\Escaper component
Zend\Stdlib component
Zend\Validator component since I'm not using the Zend framework? 2) I'm working with codeigniter framework, I appreciate your advice on how to use the class loading code. Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this at all. If you use Composer as per my answer you won't have to do any of this. It creates the autoloader for you.

Comment: @Ojchris - Sounds like you have 1) figured out.  As for 2, CI has it's own classloader.  As I recall, it has a directory under the app where you install you're own libraries.  I remember Zend being installed as well as some additional libraries that I downloaded for a site I worked on.  Unfortunately I'm blanking on that location right now.  I'll try to peek into one of my old projects and see where that directory is.

Comment: Thank you for this part of code. I just copied it, followed instructions, and it works!

Answer (score 3):

You can use Composer locally and then upload the files to the server.

I asked about this here: [Using Composer locally then uploading files through FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41224832/using-composer-locally-then-uploading-files-through-ftp)

Basically, if you can't run Composer on the server, use it locally, then copy the necessary files to the server.

The reason you should use it is because it will download the dependencies for you, without you having to manually configure a load of stuff. That's very much the point of Composer :)

```
composer require phpoffice/phpword

Using version ^0.13.0 for phpoffice/phpword

./composer.json has been created

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

  - Installing pclzip/pclzip (2.8.2)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing phpoffice/common (v0.2.6)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing zendframework/zend-stdlib (2.4.13)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing zendframework/zend-validator (2.4.13)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing zendframework/zend-escaper (2.4.13)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing phpoffice/phpword (v0.13.0)
    Downloading: 100%
```

Comment: thank you. But any idea how to get the zend components: Zend\Escaper component
Zend\Stdlib component
Zend\Validator component since I'm not using the Zend framework?

Comment: That's why you should use Composer. Because it will get the dependencies for you.

Comment: yea I forgot that. Thanks

Comment: I've just tested it locally but added to the post to show you it will download all the dependencies like Zend.

Comment: @Andy my server is behind firewall and network unreachable, but can make request. do you know which urls the composer needs to download all the dependencies?

Answer (score 3):

Here you can download PHPWord without composer: 
https://php-download.com/package/phpoffice/phpword

On this site are all libraries from the composer network but you can download all of them without a composer installation.

Comment: THIS ^^^^ I don't know how to upvote this more than once, but this is the EXACT solution I needed and, within about 5 minutes, all my problems are solved.  Thank you, thank you, thank.

Comment: That's a subscription service.  Undermines the principals of the community to be forced to subscribe to get packages that are supposed to be GNU.

Comment: This is a commercial solution!!

Answer (score -2):

**Download The PHpWord Zip FIle From Here:** https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/archive/develop.zip

> Source:: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord
>
> **PHPWord requires the following extension:**

- PHP 5.3.3+
- XML Parser extension
- Zend\Escaper component
- Zend\Stdlib component
- Zend\Validator component
- Zip extension (optional, used to write OOXML and ODF)
- GD extension (optional, used to add images)
- XMLWriter extension (optional, used to write OOXML and ODF)
- XSL extension (optional, used to apply XSL style sheet to template )
- dompdf library (optional, used to write PDF)

> **Example** Of basic usage of `PHPWord` library.
>   https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Comment: thank you. But any idea how to get the zend components: Zend\Escaper component
Zend\Stdlib component
Zend\Validator component since I'm not using the Zend framework?